# R Plotly hooverinfo - adjust the number format to show thousands separator

Tags: r, plotly

Please help:
I have a plotly graph in R where I want to change the format of the number which is shown when you hoover info on the data-point. For now, the number is shown without a comma or dot for thousand separators: e.g. the numbers are now shown like this: 15922784, and I would like it to be on the graph like this: 151,922,784 or 151.922.784. The picture of the current situation is here (the number in question has a red underline):

[image]

I am not sure if plotly has the function to change the format of the number in the hooverinfo text.
For now my code look like this:

```
HAMAG_inter %>%
   plot_ly(
         x = ~Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata_HRK, 
         y = ~Broj_ugovora,                                                                                  
         size = ~Postotak_iskorištenosti_bespovratnih_sredstava,
         color = ~Poziv, 
         frame = ~Datum,
         hoverinfo = 'text',
         text = paste('Poziv: ', HAMAG_inter$Poziv,
                                '<br>',
                     'Broj ugovora: ', HAMAG_inter$Broj_ugovora,
                                '<br>',
                     'Ukupna vrijednost, HRK: ', HAMAG_inter$Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata_HRK,
                                '<br>',
                      '% iskorištenosti sredstava: ', HAMAG_inter$Postotak_iskorištenosti_bespovratnih_sredstava,'%',
                                '<br>',
                      '% uspješno završenih ugovora:', HAMAG_inter$Postotak_završenih_ugovora_od_ugovorenih),
         type = 'scatter',
         mode = 'markers',marker = list(sizeref = 0.15))
```

Or maybe I should change how the number in question is formatted in the data frame?
The data frame and numbers in it look like this:

[image]

How do I change the format of all numbers but only in the 4th (Ugovoreni_iznos_bes...) and 5th (Ukupna_vrijednost_projekta) column to show a thousand separators. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `comma()` from `formattable` package to format the number that you want. Try this inside your `paste()`:

```r
formattable::comma(HAMAG_inter$Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata_HRK, digits = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Such an elegant solution, works perfectly.